# vertical nav bar with images + text css

Tags: html, css

At my website guestspeaker.earth I have buttons down the right hand side that are clickable to jump to other pages. Each button is a table row, split into two columns, to help me organise and align the contents. The L/H column has an image with a link, the R/H column has a heading and a paragraph containing text, all surrounded by a link anchor. It works but it generates errors because of course you shouldn't have tags within a `<a>` tag. (There are also problems with using 'width' and 'align', I know.). I'm struggling to come up with an elegant alternative. I don't want to use Java. I'm open to alternatives that don't look exactly like what I've got, if it's not possible to mimic the current layout. Any help greatly appreciated, as I'm a beginner here.

```
<table class="rightpanel"> 
<tr class="rightpanellinkbox">
<td class="rightpanellinkbox" width="90"><a href="current-bookings.htm">
<img src="images/lecture-audience.jpg" alt="Current bookings" width="70"  align="center"></a>
</td>
<td class="rightpanellinkbox"><a href="current-bookings.htm">
<h3>Current bookings</h3>
<p class="panel">Upcoming talks David is giving around the country</p></a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The CSS is:

```
table.rightpanel {
margin-left:auto;   
margin-top: 10px;
text-align: center;
background-color:#000066;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-bottom:35px;
width: 85% }    

td.rightpanellinkbox {
padding-top:2px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #0066CC }

tr.rightpanellinkbox {  padding-top:2px; }

p.panel             {  
color: white;
margin-right: 10px;
margin-left: 10px;
text-align:left;
font-size: 75% }
```

Comment: First of all, tables shouldn't be used for layout.

Comment: it's perfectly fine to use tags within tags. It's also ok to put markup into a link (as long as it is no link)

Comment: Well, there _are_ errors on your page; mostly the `width` and `align` attributes you mention already, but if you replace those with CSS, it becomes correct HTML (apart from the occasional typo, but those shouldn't be to hard to get rid of). So, what is the actual problem?

Comment: Thanks for that. I realise tables are passe, so I'm trying to find a way to do it in css. Also so that EW stops producing reams of errors becasue I'm using tags within tags. I'll have a bash at producing some code when I have time and ask for comments. Dave